# Plotly Hovertext Not Showing - Precompiled Quartile Box Plots

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot, plotly-python

I am having trouble with getting the hovertext to show up up in a precompiled quartiles Plotly Box Plot. In essence I am trying to label the outliers with their IDs.

Example 1:
Hover text working well here, you can hover over the -100 point, and the hover text 50 shows up as well as the standard hover details.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Box(
    y=[1,2,3,4,-100],
    hovertext=[10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
    showlegend=False
))

fig.show()
```

Example 2: Problem Example - Can't seem to get it working on this one. A single string works, but an array of elements does not. I have also tried ensuring the elements within the array are strings but with no success.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(
        y=[[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]],
        name="Precompiled Quartiles",
        hovertext=[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
        # hovertext='Hovetext Working!!'
    )
)

fig.update_traces(q1=[ 1], median=[ 4 ],
                  q3=[ 7 ], lowerfence=[-1],
                  upperfence=[5,], mean=[ 2.2])

fig.show()
```

Any thoughts or ideas on how to get this working would be greatly appreciated. I tried to get this working with customdata and hovertemplate with no success as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I managed to figure it out using customdata and hovertemplate afterall. Solution below:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(
    go.Box(
        y=[[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]],
        name="Precompiled Quartiles",
        customdata=[[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]],
        hovertemplate='Value: %{y}<br>Custom: %{customdata}',
    )
)

fig.update_traces(q1=[ 1], median=[ 4 ],
                  q3=[ 7 ], lowerfence=[-1],
                  upperfence=[5,], mean=[ 2.2])

fig.show()
```